# GXT - How to set the grid cell background color

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to change background color of a cell in GXT Grid, I am using GXT 3.0 .I have got one link which is related to my query( http://ui-programming.blogspot.in/2010/01/gxt-how-to-set-cell-grid-background.html) but setRenderer method is not present columnConfig in GXT 3.0 .How can i get desired output? pLz help.

Code i have done till now:-

```
ColumnConfig<Stock, Double> changeCol = new ColumnConfig<Stock, Double>(props.change(), 100, "Change");
changeCol.setCell(new AbstractCell<Double>() {

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, Double value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
          if (value == null) {
                return;
              }
   store.get(context.getIndex());
          GWT.log(DOM.getCaptureElement().getId());
      String style = "style='background-color: " + (value < 0 ? "red" : "green") + "'";
      String v = number.format(value);
       sb.appendHtmlConstant("<span " + style + " qtitle='Change' qtip='" + v + "'>" + v + "</span>");
    }
  });
```

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632458/how-to-add-css-to-selected-row-in-treegrid-gxt-3

Comment: thanx for rply willome ,The link explains about GridCellRenderer<BeanModel>  , I am using GXT 3.0 how can i use setCell and AbstractCellRenderer in order to get the output?

Comment: The accepted answer is for GXT3

Answer (score 1):

For those that need to **change cell colour based on data** in the grid, I've just had to do this (GXT 3.1) but unfortunately the solution isn't perfect.

In general, one can do custom cell rendering with `ColumnConfig.setCell(MyCell)` where 'MyCell' is a subclass of `AbstractCell`.  Unfortunately there is the problem of **'padding' in the host 'div'** which isn't coloured.  There are a few ways around this...

The **simplest way** is to:

1. `ColumnConfig.setCellPadding(false)`
2. Render your own coloured divs that fill up the whole cell (with padding if desired)

Unfortunately this doesn't play well with **single cell selection** (`CellSelectionModel`).  The css class for cell selection is obfuscated so it can't be referenced in other stylesheets. :(

My **(ugly) alternative** was to render a custom stylesheet that is linked in the module's html page (eg. Main.html).  Then I can colour cells using css 'class' instead of 'style' attributes.  IE:

1. Create a custom JSP that renders a stylesheet (content type 'text/css')
2. Link the stylesheet to the module html (after 'reset.css')
3. The stylesheet needs to have selector `td.someClass` (`.someClass` is not specific enough)
4. Use `Grid.getView().setViewConfig()` to supply a `GridViewConfig` that returns the appropriate class(es)

Unfortunately this requires a good knowledge of CSS rules and also the possible colours need to be known at user login time.

There may be **a third way** using the style attribute of the 'td' element.  Have a look at this issue from Sencha:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289347-Influencing-cell-td-style-in-a-grid&p=1057079 (work in progress)

Note that **other styling options** include:

- Various `ColumnConfig.setXxxClassName()`
- Various `ColumnConfig.setXxxStyle()`