# Bold items on the tree in sencha gxt 3.0

Tags: java, extjs, gxt

I have a problem with sencha gxt 3.0. Is it possible to bold some items on the tree? If the answer is yes, how can I do it?

Comment: add a proper css and then use below info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632458/how-to-add-css-to-selected-row-in-treegrid-gxt-3

Comment: Thanks I will try if I won't find another way, but for now I would preffer to do it without using css. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do it by setting it on the cell using  override of render method, but you will not be having the grid object to check for condition there and hence will not be applicable only for some tree objects. valueColumn.setCell(new AbstractCell<String>(){
@Override public void render(Context context, String valueString, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
  if (context.getKey()!=null && !context.getKey().equals("null") && valueString!=null && valueString.trim().length() > 0 ){
      sb.appendHtmlConstant("<b>" + valueString + "</b>"
  }
 }
});

Comment: these solutions seems to be for the TreeGrid, but I'm using just normal Tree component

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it that way:

```
final List<String> keys = getFilteredList();
filteringTree.getTree().setCell(new AbstractCell<String>() {
            @Override
            public void render(Context context, String valueString,
                    SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                Object key = context.getKey();
                System.out.println(keys.contains(key));
                if (context.getKey() != null
                        && !context.getKey().equals("null")
                        && valueString != null
                        && valueString.trim().length() > 0
                        && keys.contains(key)) {
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<b>" + valueString + "</b>");
                } else {
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant(valueString);
                }
            }
```

where getFilteredList() gets the list of elements which fit to the filter

Thanks bgth ;)